# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

### Mycomponent

```
  onFileChangedForCV(event) {
  this.details.= event.target.files[0]
  }
candidateDetails(){

    let formData = new FormData();
    let photo= formData.append('profile_pic',this.details.photo);  
    let name=this.details.name;
    let age = this.details.age;
    let cv = this.details.cv;
    let experience = this.details.experience;
    let current_salary = this.details.current_salary;
    let expected_salary = this.details.expected_salary;
    let notice_period = this.details.notice_period;
    if (this.contentEditable){
     this.detaisservice.candidateDetailsExperienced(photo(Here throwing ERROR),name,age,cv,experience,current_salary,expected_salary,notice_period)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.details.DetailsResponse = data;
               if(this.details.DetailsResponse.code =='200'){ 
                 }
        },
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log(this.details.DetailsResponse)
      );
    }
   }
```

### MyService File

```
 candidateDetailsFresher(photo:string,name:string,age:string,cv:string){
      let body = JSON.stringify({photo:photo,name:name,age:age,cv:cv});
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      console.log(body);
      console.log(options);
     return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/seeker/candidate_details/', body, options)
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);
   }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      return body || [];   
    }
    private handleError (error: any) {
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
```

Error:Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. It's showing error when i am trying  to call API in Angular 6 .Please help me to resolve this error.Ex:let photo = this.details.photo; (it working but i want to Send as FormData).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with

```
let photo= formData.append('profile_pic',this.details.photo);
```

`append` function of FormData returns `void` so basically your variable `photo` is void here and you are trying to pass the `void` value to `candidateDetailsExperienced` however it is expecting it to be `string`.

So change your photo variable of type `string`. I guess you can use `this.details.photo` instead.

You can break this line

```
let photo= formData.append('profile_pic',this.details.photo);
```

to

```
formData.append('profile_pic',this.details.photo);
let photo  = this.details.photo; //<-- you can change to other string value if reuqired.
```